# zend registry VS zend Cache

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is the difference between zend registry and zend Cache and in which scenarios we should use them.
The below line confuses me a lot.

```
$cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you got confused because of the example in the Zend documents. They saved the cache object in the Registry for later to use.

**Purpose:**

- **Zend Registry** is for global scope. Like using [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) variables in PHP. You can save a variable (or array or object) in the registry, and later on get it from anywhere (Controller, view, model, etc) whenever you need it.
- **Zend Cache** is used to improve application performance and optimization.

**Differences:**

- **Zend Registry**: *The value is for the **current page request only***. The value is **destroyed** when the current process ends.
- **Zend Cache**: *The value is for the **upcoming page requests**.* The value is **NOT destroyed** when the current process ends (the value is saved in a file).

**Example:**

- **Zend Registry**: Setting up the database connection once, add the connection in registry, then everytime you need the connection in any file just get it from the registry.
- **Zend Cache**: You fetched a big table from database that takes 5 seconds to process (Assuming the table content never changes in this example). Save it in the cache. For the upcoming requests, rather than getting the table from the database again, you get it from the cache to make this process faster, which will take 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A **registry** is often a global object that other objects can use to find common objects and services. You might think of it as the central, global object storage of your application. The registry holds objects in memory for fast access. The parts or modules of your application can be completely separated with only one dependency: the registry.

Some say that using a registry in your application leads to a bad design, because it introduces just another global variable or forces you into passing this object around. The pattern is known as Service Locator and belongs into the category of architectural patterns.

In the example you provided, the Cache object is fetched from the registry, in order to work with it. That implies, that the Cache object was set to the registry (at some time in the application flow) before.

A **cache** is an object, which provides functionality to store and retrieve data faster, then by normal access. You save the time, where data has to be recalculated or fetched from its original storage location, which would be slower. It's an optimization technique. A good example is a memory based cache on top of a disk-accessing database.

--

In which scenarios would you use them? Let's connect both to questions.

**How to access data faster?**

One possibility would be to place a cache object in between.
Next to other optimization techniques for fetching your data faster, like properly indexing a database, etc.

**How to fetch objects in my application?**

One possibility is to store them into a registry to reuse them later.
Next to other object fetching or injections techniques.

Referencing

- http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)